# VB to C#, strange return expression

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am writing C# codes from some legacy VB codes, the original VB codes are:

```
Shared Function TriangleArea(ByVal side1 As Double, ByVal side2 As Double, ByVal side3 As Double) As Double
    Dim halfP As Double
    ' evaluate half of the perimeter
    halfP = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
    TriangleArea = Math.Sqrt(halfP * (halfP - side1) * (halfP - side2) * (halfP - side3))
End Function
```

The last line inside the function seems strange.

I re-wrote in C# as:

```
public static double TriangleArea(double side1, double side2, double side3)
        {
            double halfP;
            //evaluate half of the perimeter
            halfP = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
            double TriangleArea = Math.Sqrt(halfP * (halfP - side1) * (halfP - side2) * (halfP - side3));
            return TriangleArea;
        }
```

I am not sure about the last return clause. Can any advise if I am correct?Thanks!

Comment: Use a proper naming convention. It looks confusing because your method name and return variable name are the same. By the way you can use this online tool to convert from VB to C# or other way around. http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks Hakunamatata!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB, Function name is a variable of the return type, if you assign something to the function name it would be the return value, you need not to declare and initialize a separate variable for that.

Which is not possible in `c#` you cannot assign to function name so that you need to declare an additional variable to hold the value if needed.

The first one is the old language feature inherited from `VB6` in order to help migration, you should use a variable to hold values if needed and use return statements to properly return values from the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you must assign the return value to a variable, you need to name it different than the method name. Also in your case, you might not even need a variable to store before returning the value, therefore what you need to do is change:

```
double TriangleArea = Math.Sqrt(halfP * (halfP - side1) * (halfP - side2) * (halfP - side3));
return TriangleArea;
```

into

```
return Math.Sqrt(halfP * (halfP - side1) * (halfP - side2) * (halfP - side3));
```